# Component editor doesn't immediately prompt for saving new property values

Tags: delphi, ide, custom-controls, delphi-xe7

I have a custom control which has a component editor (two different screens available through two different context menu items). In both these instances, when I change properties of the component it's editing, the IDE does not acknowledge that any changes have been made, and thus the "Save All" button in the Delphi IDE remains inactive (assuming it was inactive prior to changes).

Although the property changes have clearly been applied on the design-time control, if I immediately run the project, the changes done from the component editor haven't been applied in runtime. I've had to make minor tweaks in the form designer / object inspector to trigger the "Save All" button to become enabled, so I can actually save the changes.

Here's how I execute the context menu selection:

`TMyControlEditor` descends from `TDefaultEditor`

```
procedure TMyControlEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
begin
  case Index of
    0: begin
      ExecEditor;
    end;
    1: ...
  end;
end;

procedure TMyControlEditor.ExecEditor;
var
  F: TfrmMyControlEditor;
begin
  F:= TfrmMyControlEditor.Create(TMyControl(Component));
  try
    case F.ShowModal of
      mrOK: begin
        F.SaveTo(TMyControl(Component));
      end;
    end;
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMyControlEditor.SaveTo(ADst: TMyControl);
begin
  ADst.ThisProperty:= chkThisProperty.Checked;
  ADst.ThatProperty:= txtThatProperty.Text;
  ADst.Width:= seWidth.Value;
  ADst.Height:= seHeight.Value;
  ADst.Visible:= chkVisible.Checked;
  ... set other properties ...
end;
```

This even happens with properties which I do not even reintroduce, such as `Visible` or `Width`. If I change any property from this property editor, it does immediately show me that change in the Object Inspector. However, the rest of the IDE doesn't acknowledge that anything has changed, and thus doesn't give me the option of saving my changes.

How do I make the IDE acknowledge when changes have been made to my control's properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comments for the `IComponentEditor` interface in *DesignIntf.pas* have some advice:

> Whenever the component modifies the component is *must* call `Designer.Modified` to inform the designer that the form has been modified.

There are some typos, but the gist is clear: your component editor needs to call `Designer.Modified`.